# Building query with st_shared in QGIS

Tags: qgis, intersection, boundaries

I have a table with county polygon boundaries (named `"counties"`). I need to build a query that identifies a particular county as well as any adjoining counties that share the same border. Have tried breaking this down but I'm missing something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Virtual Layer that will query the polygon layer twice and apply the desired filtering.

go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the query

```sql
SELECT b.*
FROM myLayer a
JOIN myLayer b ON ST_INTERSECTS(a.geometry,b.geometry)
WHERE a.id <> b.id 
AND a.id = 1234
```